# how to concatenate multiple columns in oracle sql into single column only for matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle

i have below 4 columns

```
      empid | name  | dept     | ph_no
      ---------------------------------
      123   | null  |  null    | null
      124   | mike  |  science | null
      125   | null  |  physics | 789
      126   | null  |  null    | 463
      127   | john  |  null    | null
```

and i need to merge all 4 columns into single columns only for null values.
And i need something like below--

```
    empid
 ------------
  123 is missing name,dept,ph_no
  124 is missing ph_no
  125 is missing name
  126 is missing name,dept
  127 is missing dept,ph_no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `case` expressions.

```
select empid,empid||' is missing '|| 
trim(',' from 
     (case when name is null then 'name,' else '' end||
      case when dept is null then 'dept,' else '' end||
      case when ph_no is null then 'ph_no' else '' end
     )
     ) 
from tbl
```

Comment: thank you ... how can i group the the result                                            expected result
----------------
123,124,127  missing ph_no
123,125,156  missing name
123,126,127 missing dept

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vamsi and would like just to add a where clause so the "complete" ones won't be returned.

```
select empid,empid||' is missing '|| 
       case when name is null then 'name,' else '' end||
       case when dept is null then 'dept,' else '' end||
       case when ph_no is null then 'ph_no' else '' end
 from tbl
where (name is null or dept is null or ph_no is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the NVL2 function.

```
SELECT empid||' is missing '||NVL2(name, NULL, 'name, ') ||NVL2(dept, NULL, 'dept, ')||NVL2(ph_no, NULL, 'ph_no') empid
  FROM table_
```